# Check on specific condition

Tags: php, sql-server

This is my function below:

```
function Active()
{
    ............

$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT PremiumDays, PremiumStartTime FROM Premium WHERE AccountID = ?', $_SESSION['AccountID']);
if ($num_rows == -1)
{
$this->Error('ERROR');
$db->getError();
return;
}

$data = $db->doRead();
$data['Status'] = $num_rows == 0 ? '<:SHOW_NO_PREMIUM_STATUS:>' : '<b><font size="2" color="red">Premium is active - <%Days_Remaining%> days remaining.</font></b>';

$replace = array
(
'account_status'        => $data['Status'],
'days_remaining'        => $data['PremiumDays'] - date_create($data['PremiumStartTime'])->diff(date_create())->days
);

$this->content = Template::Load('account-template', $replace);
}
```

`PremiumDays` column contains numbers like `10`,`15`,`30` etc.

`PremiumStartTime` contains a date in this format `2018-12-17 21:13:00`

If there is no row found then it will display `<:SHOW_NO_PREMIUM_STATUS:>`, however, I am struggling to make it when there is a row present but `days_remaining` is `0` or negative like `-3` then to display again `<:SHOW_NO_PREMIUM_STATUS:>`

All the help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the computation of `days_remaining` before you set `$data['Status']` (but after you have determined there is valid data i.e. `$num_rows != 0`) and use it in the computation of `$data['Status']` e.g.

```
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    $data['Status'] = '<:SHOW_NO_PREMIUM_STATUS:>';
    $days_remaining = 0;
}
else {
    $days_remaining = $data['PremiumDays'] - date_create($data['PremiumStartTime'])->diff(date_create())->days;
    if ($days_remaining <= 0) {
        $data['Status'] = '<:SHOW_NO_PREMIUM_STATUS:>';
    }
    else {
        $data['Status'] = '<b><font size="2" color="red">Premium is active - <%Days_Remaining%> days remaining.</font></b>';
    }
}
$replace = array(
    'account_status' => $data['Status'],
    'days_remaining' => $days_remaining
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your query and your code, hope this will help you

```
function Active() {

    $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT PremiumDays, PremiumStartTime, (PremiumDays - DATEDIFF(day, SYSDATETIME(), PremiumStartTime)) AS days_remaining FROM Premium WHERE AccountID = ?', $_SESSION['AccountID']);
    if ($num_rows == -1) {
        $this->Error('ERROR');
        $db->getError();
        return;
    }
    $data = $db->doRead();    

    if (empty($data) || $data['days_remaining'] < 0) {
        $account_status = '<:SHOW_NO_PREMIUM_STATUS:>';
        $days_remaining = 0;
    }
    else {
        $account_status = '<b><font size="2" color="red">Premium is active - <%Days_Remaining%> days remaining.</font></b>';
        $days_remaining = $data['days_remaining'];
    }

    $replace = array(
        'account_status' => $account_status,
        'days_remaining' => $days_remaining
    );

    $this->content = Template::Load('account-template', $replace);
}
```